# Why is my Javascript not work in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts

I create function to make the first radion button is checked but my javascript is not working. When i use it in jsfiddle it work perfect but when i try in jsp page, it not working any more. Can anyone tell me what am i do wrong? I work with struts 1, and don't use any jquery libs.

This is my code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name=radioButton]')[0].checked = true;
```

```html
 <table id="tabledata" style="width: 80%" border=1>
   <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Code</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton"></td>
    <td>122222222222222</td>
    <td>4444444444444444 </td>
   </tr>
           <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton"></td>
    <td>122222222222222</td>
    <td>4444444444444444 </td>
   </tr>
            <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton"></td>
    <td>122222222222222</td>
    <td>4444444444444444 </td>
   </tr>
            <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton"></td>
    <td>122222222222222</td>
    <td>4444444444444444 </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

And this is my jsp code:

```
<html:form action="/Showdata">
    <div class="loaddata">
    <table id="tabledata" style="width: 80%" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Code</th>
            </tr>
            <logic:iterate id="listEmp" name="ShowdataForm" property="listEmp">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="radioButton"></td>
                <td><bean:write name="listEmp" property="name"/></td>
                <td><bean:write name="listEmp" property="code"/> </td>
            </tr>
            </logic:iterate>
            </table>
    </div>
</html:form>
```

Comment: If you're not using jQuery why do you have a bunch of jQuery in your code?

Comment: `my javascript is not working` - you'll have to do a LOT better than that ... how is it not working? what do you observe vs what do you expect ...HINT: most browsers have what's usually called **Developer Tools** in which you'll have a **console** - this *console* will show messages and javascript errors, useful information for javascript **_developers_** such as yourself. What does your **_code_** produce in the *console*?

Comment: You don't need to keep repeating `$(function() {`. It's equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() {`.

Comment: Oh sorry i post wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

well, the question not framed properly. I found a few errors inb the javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
//$(function() {remove this
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
 $("input:radio[name='radioButton']:visible:first").attr('checked', 'checked');
    }//why do you have a curly brace here?
);
$(function() {
    $('#tabledata tr').click(function() {
        $(this).find('tr input:radio').prop('checked', true);
    })
//});
 });
```

If you are tryin to do something when a radio button is checked try this

```
 $('input:radio[name="radioButton"]').change(
function(){
    if (this.checked && this.value == 'Yes') {
        // called on checking an <input>, not
        // on un-checking it.
    }
});

   $(document).ready(function() {//put a block of code in here to run it as soon as document loads.
    alert("page loaded");
     //no need of putting a $(function(){ }); here again
   }
```

Comment: Oh thank for help but i post the wrong code, can you review my question and help me again?